# TYPO3 blank page fluid extension

Tags: templates, typo3-8.7.x

I watched a tutorial video in Linkedin Learning about how to integrate a FLUID Template. 
I created a FLUID Template. But the template doesn't display on the page.

**My structure**

```
typo3conf/ext/october                                          
typo3conf/ext/october/Typoscript/Configuration/page.setup.ts   
typo3conf/ext/october/Typoscript/Library/setup.ts              
typo3conf/ext/october/Typoscript/Library/constants.ts          
typo3conf/ext/october/Resources/Private/Layouts/Default.html   
typo3conf/ext/october/Resources/Private/Templates/Default.html
```

**page.setup.ts**

```
page = PAGE 
page.10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
page.10 {
  templateName = Default
  templateRootPaths.10 = EXT:october/Resources/Private/Templates
  layoutRootPaths.10 = EXT:october/Resources/Private/Layouts
  partialsRootPaths.10 = EXT:october/Resources/Private/Partials
}
```

**setup.ts**

```
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="DIR:EXT:october/Configuration/TypoScript/Configuration/" extensions="setupts">
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="DIR:EXT:october/Configuration/TypoScript/Library/" extensions="setupts">
```

**constants.ts**

```
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="DIR:EXT:october/Configuration/TypoScript/Configuration/" extensions="constantsts">
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="DIR:EXT:october/Configuration/TypoScript/Library/" extensions="constantsts">
```

**Layouts/Default.html**

```
<div style="background-color:red">
<f:render section="Default"/>
</div>
```

**Templates/Default.html** I put a simple sentence

```
Mon premier Template FLUID
```

Then I activate this extension.
And I include the new extension in Typo3 Template->Include october.
But the template doesn't display. 
Where is the mistake ? What did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the URL you are refering to `/TypoScript/` when your structure says `[...]/Typoscript/` with a small letter *S*.

Some servers are actually pretty strict in the way of using captials. For example, a directory called `HTML` will be seen totally different as a directory called `Html` and `HTmL`.